# Сохранение положения списка ul при перезагрузке JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, меня интересует как можно сделать так чтобы при перезагрузке раскрывающийся список не скрывался и оставался в том же положении. Рекомендовали local storage, но тогда вопрос, что туда записывать?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("li:has(ul:has(li))").prepend('<div class="drop"></div>');
    $(".ul-dropfree div.drop").click(function() {
        if ($(this).nextAll("ul").css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideDown(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "-22px 0"
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideUp(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "0 0"
            });
        }
    });
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("ul").slideUp(400).parents("li").children("div.drop").css({
        'background-position': "0 0"
    });
});
```

```css
ul.ul-treefree {
padding-left:25px;
padding-top: 10px;
}
ul.ul-treefree ul {
margin:0;
padding-left:6px;
}
ul.ul-treefree li {
position:relative;
list-style:none outside none;
margin:0;
padding:0 0 0 19px;
line-height:23px;
}

ul.ul-treefree li:last-child {
border-left:0 none;
}

ul.ul-dropfree div.drop {
width:12px;
height:12px;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
top:9px;
left:-12px;
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAALCAIAAAD0nuopAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAE1JREFUeNpinDlzJgNlgAWI09LScEnPmjWLoAImrHpIAkwMFAMqGMGC6X44GzkIsHoQooAFTTVQKdbAwxOigyMsmIh3MC7ASHnqBAgwAD4CGeOiDhXRAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');

background-position:-11px 0;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-dropfree ul-treefree">
    <li>
        <p>1</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>1.1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>1.2</li>
            <li>
                <p>1.3</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>1.1.1</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>1.1.2</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>1.4</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>2</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>2.1</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>2.2</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>2.2.1</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>2.2.2</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Записывать тужа id'шники пунктов списка, которые открыты, например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю при каждом открытии/закрытии ветки записывать состояние ветки. Причем хранить только открытые. Поскольку у вас нету аттрибутов `id` у веток, придется запоминать номера элементов списка в виде некоторого ключа. При инициализации дерева скрывать те ветки "ключи" которых не записаны. Получается вот такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var treeState = { // объект, который хранит состояния веток
        state: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('branchOpened')) || {},
        setOpened: function(element) {
            this.state[this._getKey(element)] = true;
            this._save();
        },
        setClosed: function(element) {
            delete this.state[this._getKey(element)];
            this._save();
        },
        isClosed: function(element) {
            return !this.state[this._getKey(element)];
        },
        _save: function() {
            localStorage.setItem('branchOpened', JSON.stringify(this.state));
        },
        _getKey: function(element) {
            var ixs = [];
            $(element).parentsUntil('ul-dropfree', 'li')
                .each(function(ix, item) {
                    ixs.unshift($(item).index());
                });
            return ixs.join(',');
        }
    };
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("li:has(ul:has(li))").prepend('<div class="drop"></div>');
    $(".ul-dropfree div.drop").click(function() {
        if ($(this).nextAll("ul").css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideDown(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "-22px 0px"
            });
            // сохраняем состояние ветви
            treeState.setOpened(this);
        }
        else {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideUp(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "0px 0px"
            });
            // сохраняем состояние ветви
            treeState.setClosed(this);
        }
    });
    // эту часть немного переделал, чтобы скрывать только нужные ветви
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("ul").each(function(ix, branch) {
        $(branch).parent("li")
            .children("div.drop")
            .css({'background-position': "0 0"});
        if (treeState.isClosed(branch)) {
            $(branch).slideUp(400);
        }
    });
});
```

На всякий случай [фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/0dev/e62aa4e5/)

Заметный недостаток решения в приведенном виде - если структура дерева изменяется нужно "забывать" состояние веток. В таких случаях чтобы корректно сохранять состояние дерева можно поменять механизм формирования ключей веток (например на `id` веток, `data-*`-параметры или даже на тексты веток если они уникальные)

Comment: @ArtemDoom вообще весь код дерева стОит оформить в виде объекта или класса. По-хорошему операции скрытия и показа веток должны иметь возможность быть вызванными вне обработчика события.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю [этот скрипт](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_cookie) отлично подойдет к этой задаче.

```
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script> <!--Ссылка на скрипт-->
Выбранные галочки будут запомнены и не исчезнут даже при перезагрузке страницы.<br /><br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="ch1"> <label for="ch1">Номер раз</label> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="ch2"> <label for="ch2">Номер два</label> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="ch3"> <label for="ch3">Номер три</label> <br /><br />

  <button onClick="javascript:clearCookie();">Сбросить Cookie</button>

  <script>
    // функция устанавливающая куки, хранящие состояния checkbox'ов
    function cookieFromCheckbox()
    {
      var ch = [];
      $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
        var $el = $(this);
        if($el.prop("checked"))
          ch.push($el.attr("id"));
      });

      $.cookie("checkboxCookie", ch.join(','));
    }

    // функция восстанавливающая состояния checkbox'ов по кукам
    function checkboxFromCookie()
    {
      if($.cookie("checkboxCookie") == null)
        return;
      var chMap = $.cookie("checkboxCookie").split(',');
      for (var i in chMap)
        $('#'+chMap[i]).prop("checked", true);
    }

    // функция сбрасывающая куки с значениями checkbox'ов
    function clearCookie()
    {
      $.cookie("checkboxCookie", null);
    } 

    // проверим, были ли установлены ранее кукисы с именем checkboxCookie.
    // если нет - установим их.
    var checkboxCookie = $.cookie("checkboxCookie");
    if(checkboxCookie == null)
    {
      cookieFromCheckbox();
      checkboxCookie = $.cookie("checkboxCookie");
    }
    else
      checkboxFromCookie();

    $("input:checkbox").change(function(){
      cookieFromCheckbox();
    });
  </script>
```